# Restore Windows 7 in cmd?

Tags: windows-7, windows, restore

I need to restore the system to an earlier point using cmd since it freezes, but I only find it using rstrui.exe, I need to do everything from the cmd itself.

There's any way to do this?

Comment: did you have the chance to test my answer? I'm curious if it worked or not

Comment: Yeah it totally worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following procedure should do what you want:

- in cmd type `powershell` to start PowerShell
- when PowerShell is started, type `start-process powershell -verb runas` to get it elevated.
- use `get-computerrestorepoint` to get available restore points. remember the `SequenceNumber` it returns
- use `Restore-Computer -restorepoint <sequencenumber>` to start the restore.

Note: Maybe you want to add `-WhatIf` to your `Restore-Computer` call, just to be sure of what it does.

More information on: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849845.aspx